# please help me with the inheritance from this superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, hashmap, superclass

I want to determine the maximum mark of an array which contains the students' name of a classroom and their marks. to do this, I have a superclass like `Person` which contains `getName()`, `Max()` and `print()` abstract methods and should not to be changed.

I have a subclass with the name `Student` which should extend from the `Person`superclass. This subclass should hold the students' information and get the maximum mark of the classroom and then print it. The main class name is `Points`. I have used a hashmap to store the marks in its values. How could I use this values in the `Max()` method and how to use the `Print()` method to show the maximum mark and the student's name. thanks.

Here is what I wrote.

the `Person` superclass:

```
public abstract class Person {
private String name;

Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public abstract void Max();

public abstract void Print();

}
```

the `Student` subclass:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Student extends Person {
Map<String, Integer> scores = new HashMap<>();

Student(String name) {
    super(name);
    String[] bits = name.trim().split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
        int Marks = Integer.parseInt(bits[1]);
        scores.put(bits[0], Marks);
    }
}

@Override
public void Max() {

}

@Override
public void Print() {

}

}
```

The `Points` main class:

```
public class Points {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] Marks = new String[] { "Student1 12",
            "Student2 90",
            "Student3 45",
            "Student4 76", 
            "Student5 58", };
    for (int i = 0; i < Marks.length; i++) {
        Student std = new Student(Marks[i]);
        std.getName();
        std.Max();
        std.Print();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

By the concepts of inheritance, what you're saying here is:

Each `Student`, is a `Person`. This is OK.

But, each `Person`, can only access its own data, not others' data, including name, score & ... . It only has access to its own data.

In the definition of your `Points` main class, you filled the array Marks with the information of the students, so the `Points` class has access to all the students. Therefore, its ideal to implement methods which deal with more than one object, in the class that maintains all of them.

Two tips here:

- You really didn't need a `HashMap` for the `Student` class. Every `Student` only stores its own name and score, and not all students' names and scores. `HashMap` is used whenever you want to store several values of the same kind, but with different indicators, so you can find one value easily.
- Try to make your `main` method as short as possible. For example, you can create a class `Program` with a `run()` method and only instantiate that `Program` class and call its `run()` method, in the `main` method.

Comment: It is said to me you should do it with using a hashmap. I just don't know how to override `Print()` and `Max()` methods and call them. I am new with superclasses.

Comment: I think if there's a place in your code that a `HashMap` must be used, it should only be the `Points` class, instead of that `Marks` array.

You should implement the `Max()` and `Print()` methods in the main class. However, it would be best if you made a driver class for your program.

In fact, I don't see any needs of inheritance in your program. You could just make the class `Student` and then maintain all the records in a driver object. There are definitely better examples of using inheritance:

For example, look at some RPG games. You'll instantly recognize the uses of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

change the Point class like below , call max , print methods outside for loop.

write logic for max and print methods. inside max method use directly the hashmap to retrive max values.

also you are creating hashmap for each object you create and hence for each name it will create new hashmap and hence you will get last name always from max method.

so make hashmap as static inside Student class like below

```
static Map<String, Integer> scores = new HashMap<>();
```

see the whole code below

Person.java

```
package com.kb.studentMaxMarks;

import java.util.Map.Entry;

public abstract class Person {
private String name;

public Person() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
Person(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public abstract Entry<String, Integer> Max();

public abstract void Print(Entry<String, Integer> entry);

}
```

Student.java

```
package com.kb.studentMaxMarks;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Student extends Person {
static Map<String, Integer> scores = new HashMap<>();

Student(String name) {
    super(name);
    String[] bits = name.trim().split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++) {
        int marks = Integer.parseInt(bits[1]);
       // System.out.println(marks);
        scores.put(bits[0], marks);
    }
}

@Override
public Entry<String, Integer> Max() {
    System.out.println("inside max");

     Map.Entry<String,Integer> maxEntry = null;
     //System.out.println(" max value of map "+maxValueInMap);
    for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : scores.entrySet()) {
         if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue().compareTo(maxEntry.getValue()) > 0)
            {
                maxEntry = entry;
            }
    }
    //System.out.println(maxEntry.getValue());
    return maxEntry;

}

@Override
public void Print(Entry<String, Integer> entry) {
    System.out.println("name "+entry.getKey()+" score "+entry.getValue());

}

}
```

Points.java

```
package com.kb.studentMaxMarks;

import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Points {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] Marks = new String[] { "Student1 12",
            "Student2 90",
            "Student3 45",
            "Student4 76", 
            "Student5 58", };
    Student std = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < Marks.length; i++) {
         std = new Student(Marks[i]);
        std.getName();
    }
    Entry<String, Integer> entry = std.Max();
    std.Print(entry);
}

}
```

let me know for any issues.

Comment: thanks. Now I dont know how to override the max method for example when I write this code I only get the last student's mark: `@Override
 public void Max() {
  
        System.out.println(scores.values());
    }`

Comment: max should work to return max score student's details only right? can you show what logic you used to find the max value

Comment: see the updated answer, to make map as static inside student class.

Comment: Actually I don't know how to use the Logic to find it in the Max() method Because I don't know how to get all the values of the hashmap there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. But now I don't know how to print this result in the abstract `Print()` method. I mean I don't know how to pass it to the `Print()` method and then show the answer.

Comment: see updated complete code..if you satisfy with the answer then please voteup and accept the answer